# How to make nodejs server ignore DOM errors on startup?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dom, window

I am using a react package, react-image-show, that uses window in it's node_modules file, and that creates a "window is not defined" error on deploy. How can I make my nodejs ignore this DOM references until startup ? Because after startup, the window object and all the other DOM objects will exist .
How can I manage this ?